# Azure AD Connect: how to add Azure AD users to on-premise Domain Controller?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-connect

I successfully installed Azure AD Connect on my domain controller which is an Azure VM. However, my Azure AD users are not in the Domain.

My goal is to be able to login on my workstation which is part of the domain using my Office 365 credentails. which is already part of Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

User Writeback was a *preview* feature in an earlier release of AAD Connect.  However, it was removed in version 1.0.8667.  When this will be added back into the tool is unknown at this time.

Comment: I donwloaded the latest version (1.0.8667 of 8/20/2015.) of  Azure AD Connect and I used Custom Settings. I don't see the option for "User writeback". I see grayed out options for Device and Group writeback. What do I need to do to make it available?

Comment: @IgorGatis I just learned that this feature was removed in this update and updated my answer to reflect this new information.